# Maven build hangs during build

Tags: maven, aem, maven-archetype

Whenever I run the maven build on my POM.xml, the build just hangs and the laptop becomes unresponsive. The last lines I always see are:

```
[INFO] --- filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.0.3:check-signature (default-check-signature) @ my-project.ui.apps ---
[INFO] No signature defined. Skipping signature check.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.0.3:analyze-classes (default-analyze-classes) @ my-project.ui.apps ---
[INFO] Analyzing java package dependencies.
```

The plugin configuration in my POM file is below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>filevault-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <filterSource>src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml</filterSource>
        <failOnDependencyErrors>false</failOnDependencyErrors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am trying to build this using archetype 22. The same code and dependencies worked fine in archetype 13 project earlier.

Comment: Have you tried attaching to the maven process and getting some kind of stacktrace/thread dump?

Comment: does it hangs in other machines as well?